# User not existend in the database JWT?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, jwt

So i have got a slight problem with the user authentication with JWT token. When i Login it returns to me "user doesnt exist", although there's clearly an user in the database. I've tried to fix by not looking for the password in the database and comparing it and it worked, but my question is how can i compare passwords in mongoose database and check if the user exists?

Login route:

```
//create route for sign in
router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    //destructure email and password from req.body
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    })
    if (!user) res.status(400).send({ message: 'User doesnt exist' })
    else {
        const valid = compare(req.body.password, user.password)
        if (!valid) res.send(400).send({ message: 'Password doesnt match' })

        if (valid) {
            const accesstoken = createAccessToken(user._id)
            const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken(user._id)
            return res.send({
            email: user.email,
            refreshtoken: user.refreshtoken,
            sendAccessToken: sendAccessToken(req, accesstoken),
            sendRefreshToken: sendRefreshToken(refreshtoken),
        })
        }
    }
})
```

user Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10
// const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

//how a user will be stored in the mongodb schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 6, trim: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
    refreshtoken: { type: String },
})

const userModel = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)

module.exports = userModel
```

login page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { userContext } from '../../App'
// import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
// import { login } from '../../actions/userActions'

function Login(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(userContext)
    //acces the userLogin from redux store
    // const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
    // const { loading, userInfo, error } = userLogin

    // const dipsatch = useDispatch()
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if (userInfo) {
    //         props.history.push('/')
    //     }
    // }, [userInfo])

    //handlesubmit
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const result = await (
            await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/signin', {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email,
                    password,
                }),
            })
        ).json()
        if (result.accesstoken) {
            setUser({
                accesstoken: result.accesstoken,
            })
            window.location = '/'
        } else {
            alert(result.error)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user)
    }, [user])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="login-h">Login</h1>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login">
                <div className="login-form">
                    <label>email</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="username or email"
                        for="email"
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                    <br />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        for="password"
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                    <br />
                    <p className="forget-pw">
                        <a href="/">Forgot password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <button>Login</button> <br />
                    <br />
                    {/* <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{result.error}</p> */}
                </div>
                <p className="have-ccl">
                    {' '}
                    No account yet?<a href="/signup">Signup</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: are you even hashing your password?

Comment: @Ifaruki i am not hashing my password?

Comment: so whenever an user get saved into the database you save his plain password without hashing it?

Comment: @Ifaruki no, because when the user registers it hashes the password.

Comment: okey, but why did you added `passwords: req.body.password` to your find query? you only need `email: req.body.email`, then you check if the users exist, and then you compare the hashed password with the plain password with `bcrypt.compare` if you use bcrypt

Comment: when i look at your code removing `password: req.body.password,` should be the fix

Comment: @Ifaruki it does kind of fix it, but i get the following error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: the error is at res.send

Comment: try adding `return` before every `res` witch will stop the execution

Comment: what does `sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken)` do? does it send an response back?

Comment: @Ifaruki it sends the refreshtoken

Comment: so you already send an response back there? you can send just 1 response back

Comment: @Ifaruki if i dont send a response back will it affect the functionality heavily?
Can i still access the data ?

Comment: you need to send an response back. send it with `res.send({ ... })` and put every information what your frontend needs into that object

Comment: @Ifaruki alright, thanks for your help. I appreciate it

Comment: the information "user does not exist" and "password doesn't match should not sent in this form to the frontend. There should be one message for both cases.

Comment: @Ifaruki check the edited res.send({}) its not a valid function is it? 
it throws me an error: TypeError: res.send is not a function

Comment: where does the error appear? and you have 2x send here `res.send(400).send({ message: 'Password doesnt match' })`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

1. Remove the unnecessary `password: req.body.password` line from your mongoose query. This is basically comparing unhashed passwords with hashed passwords in a plain JavaScript object. This never returns true because the hash is always different from the unhashed password.
2. Is it possible that your body is never actually sent? You need to add the `name` attribute to inputs before they can be parsed. Are you using `body-parser`?